# How to add new key in existing array in angular js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have define blank array $scope.order, ON form submit data get and create new array then merge with existing array.

```
.controller('GuestDetailsCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.order = [];
    $scope.itemDetails = function() {
        // Here data get after form submiti have array arrieve from form submit.
        $scope.order=$scope.order.push({name:$scope.item.name,price:$scope.item.price});
    }
});
```

I want result like this.

> $scope.order = [{name:'abc',price:100},{name:'pqr',price:80},{name:'xyz',price:50}];
>   
>   When itemDetails() call at that time array merge with new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` operates on the array in-place. Simply

```
$scope.order = [];
$scope.itemDetails = function() {
    // Here data get after form submiti have array arrieve from form submit.
    $scope.order.push({name:$scope.item.name,price:$scope.item.price});
}
```

(without assigning it), and that should work!