# Repeat an item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects whereby there is a need to allow the user to add an item that is a duplicate of another. It is triggered when they increase the quantity where a property called 'HasPers' is true.

The HTML markup looks like:

```
<td width="10%"><input type="number" value="{{productdetails.Quantity}}" ng-model="productdetails.Quantity" min="1" ng-change="change(productdetails)" /></td>
```

and the function is:

```
$scope.change = function (item) {
        if (item.HasPers) {
             item.Quantity = 1;
             $scope.items.push(item);
         }
       };
```

Initially this had a problem in the repeater wherby it knew it was a duplicat object but this was solved by adding  'track by $index' in the repeater

```
<tr ng-repeat="productdetails in items track by $index">
```

http://mutablethought.com/2013/04/25/angular-js-ng-repeat-no-longer-allowing-duplicates/

but the item is clearly still associated with the original since when I change some properties on the original one they change on the duplicate one too. I really want to avoid typing out all of the properties again as in

[How to add new key in existing array in angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635512/how-to-add-new-key-in-existing-array-in-angular-js)

is there any way to create a new item that is identical to the one being passed in but is a different object?

Comment: Use angular.copy to copy the original item

Comment: thanks. that worked perfectly

Comment: welcome ,You should use angular.copy when copying element from and adding to the same source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using angular.copy

```
 $scope.change = function (item) {
    if (item.HasPers) {
    var newItem = angular.copy(item);
         newItem.Quantity = 1;
         $scope.items.push(newItem);
     }
   };
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$scope.change = function (item) {
    if (item.HasPers) {
         var copyItem=angular.copy(item);
         copyItem.Quantity = 1;
         $scope.items.push(copyItem);
     }
   };
```